# Running patch within a function

Tags: python, xml, subprocess, patch

I need to make some changes to an xml using a 'patch.txt' file, generated with diff, within a function.

I am able to do this on the command line with:

```
patch export.xml patch.txt
```

but when I use

```
subprocess.run(["patch" "export.xml patch.txt"])
```

within a function, this process is not called.

Any ideas on how to perform patching within python code?

Answer (score 0):

Space is the separator for the shell input. So the code should be:

```
subprocess.run(["patch", "export.xml", "patch.txt"])
```